# LateError (LateInitializationError: Field if i call function from parent widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am using youtube_player_flutter

as document of youtube_player_flutter `_playerController.load(videoId.toString())` this function is use to change video and its working fine when i call this function in same widget

```
void changeVideo(videoId) {
    this._playerController.load(videoId.toString());
  }
```

but when i try to call this `changeVideo` from parent widget

```
WatchState().changeVideo(video.toString());
```

its show me error

```
LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_playerController@43012897' has not been initialized.)
```

thanks

Comment: Do you have a variable `_playerController`? If so please show that code.

Comment: `late YoutubePlayerController _playerController;` like this

Comment: @MendelG https:// we.tl/t-l9932GAMsN here is 2 files 1 parent which is root_page and 1 is watch which is child

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize PlayerController in your parent widget. Try to do that and let me know if it works :)

Comment: And also try to inject the PlayerController into your widget as a parameter.